# Flutter chrome web app login screen never-ending loop with LinkedIn API authorization

Tags: flutter, web-applications, linkedin-api, flutter-provider, flutter-change-notifier

After a long time getting the port to allow the LinkedIn API to send the redirect URI by using the command `flutter run -d chrome --web-port=3000` the issue is now it just opens a new tab in the window like a new instance of the app, which then resets the _user information in my widget build since everything's restarting. This causes the user to continuously have to log back in. If I keep logging in to LinkedIn's API, then there will be tons of new tabs being created and new app instances. Why didn't the login screen redirect the user back to the same tab, or why is my shared preferences or provider attempts working. The login screen should recognize when it's finished and the app can move to the next state after the user gives authorization to the API.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_web_auth/flutter_web_auth.dart';
import 'package:linkedin_login/linkedin_login.dart';
import 'linkedin_api_auth.dart';
import 'linkedin_share.dart';
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

//==================
//   Connect Page
//==================

class ConnectPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ConnectPage({super.key});
  final UserModel userModel = UserModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: userModel,
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
        darkTheme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.2), //better
          body: const Linkedin_Login(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//==================
//    API Auth
//==================

class AuthCodeObject {
  AuthCodeObject({required this.code, required this.state});

  final String code;
  final String state;
}

class UserObject {
  UserObject({
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.email,
    required this.profileImageUrl,
  });

  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String email;
  final String profileImageUrl;

  get profilePicture => String;

  static dynamic fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> userInfo) {
    return UserObject(
      firstName: userInfo['firstName']['localized']['en_US'].toString(),
      lastName: userInfo['lastName']['localized']['en_US'].toString(),
      email: userInfo['emailAddress'].toString(),
      profileImageUrl: userInfo['profilePicture']['displayImage~']['elements']
              [0]['identifiers'][0]['identifier']
          .toString(),
    );
  }
}


//==========================
// Change Provider UserModel
//==========================

class UserModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  UserObject? _user;
  bool _logoutUser = false;

  UserObject? get user => _user;
  bool get logoutUser => _logoutUser;

  void setUser(UserObject user) {
    _user = user;
    print('UserModel - setUser, _user: $_user');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setLogoutUser(bool value) {
    _logoutUser = value;
    print('UserModel - setLogoutUser, bool value: $value');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Linkedin_Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Linkedin_Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Linkedin_Login> createState() => _Linkedin_LoginState();
}

class _Linkedin_LoginState extends State<Linkedin_Login> {
  //_user is never initialized
  //UserObject? _user;
  bool logoutUser = false;
  late http.Client httpClient;

  Future<void> _onLinkedInLogin(UserObject? user, UserModel userModel) async {
    userModel.setUser(user!);
  }

  Future<void> _login() async {
    final authorizationUrl = LinkedIn.getAuthorizationUrl().toString();

    final result = await FlutterWebAuth.authenticate(
      url: authorizationUrl,
      //callbackUrlScheme: LinkedIn.redirectUri,
      callbackUrlScheme: 'http',
      //callbackUrlScheme: 'tng',
    );

    final code = Uri.parse(result).queryParameters['code'];

    if (code != null) {
      final token = await LinkedIn.getToken(code);
      final userInfo =
          await LinkedIn.getUserInfo(token['access_token'] as String);
      setState(() {
        final userModel = Provider.of<UserModel>(context, listen: true);

        userModel.setUser(UserObject.fromJson(userInfo) as UserObject);
      });
    }
  }

  //void _logout(UserModel userModel) {
  //Future<void> _logout() async {
  void _logout() {
    // final UserModel userModel = UserModel();
    final userModel = Provider.of<UserModel>(context);
    print('_Linkedin_LoginState - _logout called');
    setState(() {
      userModel.setLogoutUser(true);
      print('_Linkedin_LoginState - setLogoutuser(true)');
      //_user = '' as UserObject;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userModel2 = Provider.of<UserModel>(context, listen: true);
    return Consumer<UserModel>(
      builder: (context, userModel, child) {
        final user = userModel2.user;
        final logoutUser = userModel2.logoutUser;
        print('_Linkedin_LoginState: user = ${userModel.user}');
        print('_Linkedin_LoginState: logoutUser = ${userModel.logoutUser}');
        if (logoutUser) {
          //_logout(userModel);
          _logout();
          userModel.setLogoutUser(false);
          return ElevatedButton(
            //onPressed: () => _logout(userModel),
            onPressed: () => _logout(),
            child: const Text('Logged out. Click to log in again.'),
          );
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('LinkedIn Screen!!'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: user != null
                  ? Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Image.network(
                          user.profilePicture?.displayImageElements?.first
                                  ?.identifiers?.first?.identifier
                                  .toString() ??
                              '',
                          width: 100,
                          height: 100,
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),
                        Text('Hello, ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}!'),
                        const SizedBox(height: 16),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: _logout,
                          child: const Text('Logout'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  : ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: _login,
                      child: const Text('Login with LinkedIn'),
                    ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

//==================
// LinkedIn API Auth
//==================

class LinkedIn {
  static const String clientId = '[clientId ]';
  static const String clientSecret = '[clientSecret ]';
  //static const String redirectUri = 'http://example.com:8000/oauth2callback';
  static const String redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3333/oauth/callback';
  static const String scope = 'r_emailaddress r_liteprofile w_member_social';

  static const String authorizationEndpoint =
      'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization';
  static const String tokenEndpoint =
      'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken';
  static const String userInfoEndpoint =
      'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams))';

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getToken(String code) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(tokenEndpoint),
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
      body: {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': redirectUri,
        'client_id': clientId,
        'client_secret': clientSecret,
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Failed to retrieve access token');
    }

    return json.decode(response.body) as Future<Map<String, dynamic>>;
  }

  static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserInfo(String accessToken) async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(userInfoEndpoint),
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'},
    );

    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      throw Exception('Failed to retrieve user info');
    }

    return json.decode(response.body) as Future<Map<String, dynamic>>;
  }

  static Uri getAuthorizationUrl() {
    return Uri.parse(
        '$authorizationEndpoint?response_type=code&client_id=$clientId&redirect_uri=$redirectUri&scope=$scope');
  }
}
```

I've been kind of slow at learning how Provider works and Shared Preferences with Consumer, I actually didn't know those were two different things, and I'm totally new at API's and authorization, I just wanted to learn this for a project because it seems very useful to know in general.

I tried making this UserModel with ChangeNotifier, and also have some print statements in the widget build:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final userModel2 = Provider.of<UserModel>(context, listen: true);
    return Consumer<UserModel>(
      builder: (context, userModel, child) {
        final user = userModel2.user;
        final logoutUser = userModel2.logoutUser;
        print('_Linkedin_LoginState: user = ${userModel.user}');
        print('_Linkedin_LoginState: logoutUser = ${userModel.logoutUser}');
```

These print statements always show null values and false every time, no matter what I do. The user logs in and there's no persistence of their login so they have to just keep logging in over and over.

```
//==========================
// Change Provider UserModel
//==========================

class UserModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  UserObject? _user;
  bool _logoutUser = false;

  UserObject? get user => _user;
  bool get logoutUser => _logoutUser;

  void setUser(UserObject user) {
    _user = user;
    print('UserModel - setUser, _user: $_user');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setLogoutUser(bool value) {
    _logoutUser = value;
    print('UserModel - setLogoutUser, bool value: $value');
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```